# Code / template  generator for Java

Tags: java, templates, code-generation

For C#, I have often used [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) and lately the [T4 generator](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) which is part of Visual Studio.

I'm looking for something similar for Java, in particular an Eclipse add-in since I do all my Java development using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What are you trying to generate specifically?

Answer (score 6):

I've found that [freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) does a pretty good job for generating any type of code. From the website:

> FreeMarker is a "template engine"; a generic tool to generate text output (anything from HTML to autogenerated source code) based on templates. It's a Java package, a class library for Java programmers. It's not an application for end-users in itself, but something that programmers can embed into their products.

It is used by struts2 a lot. The website has a long list of other products that use freemarker.

Answer (score 6):

I have worked with both [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) and [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/). Velocity is a bit more conventional (think JSP/ASP concepts), while StringTemplate seems a bit cleaner. in a sense described in [this Artima interview](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/stringtemplate.html). Both are pure templating engines, and will require you to write some code around them, if you want to do full-blown code generation from a model.

StringTemplate is used internally by [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), which may be useful to your effort.

As an alternative approach, you could go with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), using [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) and [JET](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should try Telosys Tools, an Eclipse plugin for code generation working from an existing database with customizable Velocity templates

See: http://www.telosys.org/

Eclipse Marketplace : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

The tutorials are here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

See this other question about CodeSmith : [Is there any freeware tool available which is like Codesmith?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035599/is-there-any-freeware-tool-available-which-is-like-codesmith/24323355#24323355)

Answer (score 2):

I use [JavaForger](https://github.com/daanvdh/JavaForger) to generate code from templates. It parses existing classes so that you can use that [class-data](https://github.com/daanvdh/JavaForger/blob/master/TemplateVariables.md) inside your templates. It can both create new classes or insert code into existing classes. You can determine where generated code will be inserted based on a string conversion rule (e.g. myProject/dao/ProductDao.java => myProject/service/ProductService.java).

JavaForger is open source and uses [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart.html) as template engine and [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/) as parser.

Comment: The docs are inadequate to tell if it is usable by only declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the only thing that comes close (for Java) to do what CodeSmith Generator does is [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo).

The reason is that Java does not have Partial Classes like C# does. Spring Roo gets around this by using [AspectJ ITDs](http://spring-roo.blogspot.com/2011/10/quick-introduction-to-aspectj-itd.html).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to use StringTemplate, but there is a bit more to it than just what tool to use.

Is it the issue to generate java code? Or is it to use java tools? Programmers would be normally very comfortable writing code. Therefore, it would not be a leap to write some java classes and write a walk that would generate code using StringTemplate. I personally think it is a good exercise to create example models, generate your java code from the models. And depending on your use case you could end up writing JSON models by hand and never having to write any java code to produce the java code. Or you could end up writing Java classes that produce equivalent models.

You could use the StringTemplate based [STST](http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2007/04/26/on-learning-stringtemplate/), which reads JSON. STST is command line based, and I am sure you could hook it to both eclipse and/or Visual Studio.

I personally think about portability, JSON is an extremely simple language. And almost every language has libraries that support it.

Comment: Command line, please?
A pure declaration Maven plugin is the only thing that I'm interested, anything boring should be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# man so I don't know what the equivalents would be, however I've found [xdoclet](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/index.html) to be very good in the past. I don't think it integrates with eclipse as such but you can run it from an ant script. Does things like generating Hibernate mapping files from annotated Java classes. Useful if that's what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

eclipse has a built-in template system.

look in window -> preferences -> java -> code style -> code templates

Answer (score 0):

You might look at my plugin : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/. It allows one to select multiple fields and generate code using user specified velocity templates.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my project https://github.com/karajdaar/templator and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple web based application for my use.
its available at https://github.com/harish2704/templates
 and a demo is available at http://templates-harish2704.rhcloud.com/
Its language independent tool. GUI supports several languages ( highlighting, snippet completion ect )